# Angular: Persistent user data

Tags: angular, authentication, storage

I'm not so new in `angular` (or any other one - `react`, `vue.js`), but I still don't know how to save efficiently user data in the client browser.

Currently, my backend is already working fine, sending a `token` when a pre-registered user tries to log in with using good inputs.

I've read something using [angular-storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-storage)(way better than `localStorage`) and since I, as a user, can have access to it and modify it, am not sure if it's a secure method.

I thought because of guards offered by angular which I can simply modify to go across.

Thank you for an answer!

Comment: What type of data do you want to store? And what would happen if the user modified that?

Comment: I want to save the user token and some of the user core informations as the id and the name.

Comment: in many uses of cases ... you need to store on sessionStorage if data only persist on tab time in browser, and use localStorage y data will persist even the browser closes. to save data what ever you choose of them is `sessionStorage.set('tagName', value)`.

Comment: Yeah, I also read about that. But the app isn't going only to last one tab. It's thought to last long in the memory.